# CasperJS weird evaluate behavior

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

So, I have this code...

```
var config = require('./config.js');
var casper = require('casper').create(config.casper);

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

function run () {

    casper.start();

    casper.thenOpen('https://twitter.com', function () {
        if ( this.exists('form[action="https://twitter.com/sessions"].signin') ) {
            this.echo('logging in...');
            this.evaluate(function (username, password) {
                document.querySelector('#signin-email').value = username;
                document.querySelector('#signin-password').value = password;
                document.querySelector('.flex-table-btn').click();
            }, config.users.user.twitter.username, config.users.user.twitter.password); 
        } else {
            this.echo('Alreaddy logged in, proceed...');
        }
    });

    casper.waitForSelector('#tweet-box-mini-home-profile', function () {
        if ( this.exists('#tweet-box-mini-home-profile') ) {
            this.evaluate(function (text) {
                document.querySelector('div#tweet-box-mini-home-profile.tweet-box.rich-editor.notie').innerText = text;
                document.querySelector('button.btn.primary-btn.tweet-action.js-tweet-btn').click();
            }, 'Test using automation');
            this.wait(10000, function () {
                this.echo ('Finished waiting, closing app now');
            }); //wait for 10 seconds before closing
        } else {
            this.echo('Failed to logging in');
        }
    });

    casper.run();

}

run();
```

The logging in part works just fine, I could logging in onto the dashboard.

But the second step, the tweeting step throw an error

```
Page Error: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector('div#tweet-box-mini-home-profile.tweet-box.rich-editor.notie').innerText = text')
```

and the tweet won't got posted. I've tried it manually on the browser and it works just fine.

```
var config = require('./config.js');
var casper = require('casper').create(config.casper);

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});


function run () {

    casper.start();

    casper.thenOpen('https://twitter.com', function () {
        if ( this.exists('form[action="https://twitter.com/sessions"].signin') ) {
            this.echo('logging in...');
            this.evaluate(function (username, password) {
                document.querySelector('#signin-email').value = username;
                document.querySelector('#signin-password').value = password;
                document.querySelector('.flex-table-btn').click();
            }, config.users.dida.twitter.username, config.users.dida.twitter.password); 
        } else {
            this.echo('Alreaddy logged in, proceed...');
        }
    });

    casper.waitForSelector('#tweet-box-mini-home-profile', function () {
        if ( this.exists('#tweet-box-mini-home-profile') ) {
            this.evaluate(function (text) {
                console.log('=========== Putting text ============');
                document.querySelector('#tweet-box-mini-home-profile > div').innerHTML = text;
            }, 'Test using automation');
        } else {
            this.echo('Failed to logging in');
        }
    });

    casper.then(function () {
        if ( this.exists('.js-tweet-btn') ) {
            //recheck the tweet
            this.echo(this.getHTML('#tweet-box-mini-home-profile'));
            this.echo('============= Clicking Submit Button ==============');
            this.click('.js-tweet-btn');
            this.wait(10000, function () {
                this.echo ('Finished waiting, closing app now');
            }); //wait for 10 seconds before closing
        } else {
            this.echo('Submit button not found');
        }
    })

    casper.run();

}

run();
```

this works, but it only tweet : "Compose new Tweet" 
as if the text never change.

So my question is, did I do something wrong or this is some kind of bug? If so, is that a workaround? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use fillSelectors() or fillXPath() methods for filling forms.

And make sure that selector 'div#tweet-box-mini-home-profile.tweet-box.rich-editor.notie' is correct.

Comment: `fillSelectors` and it's friends only work well on forms that don't have any custom javascript behaviour. Many forms have additional functionality that require dispatching `change, keyup, click,... events` on it's elements.